# Weak entity with 2 owner entities

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database I am trying to design with 3 entities: Store, Item, and Wishlist. Stores and Wishlists exist on their own, and are therefore strong. Items, however, will not exist *unless* they are either in stock at a store and/or on someone's wishlist.

I know how to handle entities that have one owner entity, but in this situation the item can exist in a store but not any wishlist, and vice versa.

My question is this: is there a way to map this odd relationship, or do I need to make 2 entities for items: one for wishlist items and one for store items.

Comment: Are you certain that the `Item` entity even serves a purpose here?  If someone wants something, and it `EXISTS` in some store, then doesn't that mean it is in inventory somewhere?

Comment: Since you use term *entity* do you use any particular language? ORM framework? so far sql relations seem obvious to me `(id, owner_id, owner_type)`

Comment: The purpose of the item is to store multiple attributes. The items are going to be vinyl records, so there's a decent amount of info to be stored i.e. album title, artist, year, label, genre, and most importantly the primary key serial number. The items need this extra info because it is unlikely the shoppers will know the exact serial number of the record they want. It's also not possible to simply have a database of all records for obvious reasons, so the records will not exist on their own if not at a store or on a wishlist.

Comment: Also yes the plan is to use sql for the database.

Comment: Are you certain that `item` is/should be weak? Is it e.g. part of the task description?

Comment: Just read your comment: just because you add an entry for *practical* reasons only when you need it doesn't mean that you couldn't add it beforehand - where I assume that "serial number" means EAN/UPC/ISBN or whatever code identifies a record *in general* (not that specific actual physical item).

Comment: Why care?  If you ignore the issue, you might have some items that are neither in stores nor in wishlists.  Will that matter?  If it does matter, please provide the SQL where it matters _and_ the app cannot take evasive action for this edge case.